# Show $P(0<X<2(\lambda+1)) \gt \lambda/(\lambda+1)$

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions

We have the following distribution function:

$$f(x) = {(e^{-x}x^\lambda)}/\lambda!$$

for $x\gt 0$ and for some $\lambda \gt 0$. We want to show:
$$P(0<X<2(\lambda+1)) \gt \lambda/(\lambda+1)$$
I found that $E(X) = V(X) = \lambda+1$
.
I tried using this with Markov's inequality, but it does not yield the correct answer.
Any suggestions?
Also, does anyone know the name of this distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this as $P(-E[X]<X-E[X]<E[X]) = P(|X-E[X]|<E[X]) = 1 - P(|X-E[X]|\geq E[X]) \geq 1 - \frac{(\lambda+1)}{(\lambda+1)^2} = \frac{\lambda^2 +\lambda}{(\lambda+1)^2} = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda+1}$. We used Chebychev's inequality in the making of this result